# Does the file browser in Chrome OS send data across the network?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

Chrome OS does allow syncing with Google Drive, which obviously does send data through the network, but what about the local file system?

Comment: IIRC ChromeOS only uses local storage for caching; thus the question is a tautology. "Does an operating system that is designed to use the network as primary storage send file data across the internet?" Yes, it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

> Chrome's Filesystem and Sync Filesystem APIs extend the HTML5 FileSystem API. With Chrome's Filesystem API, apps can create, read, navigate, and write to a sandboxed section of the user's local file system. For example, a photo-sharing app can use the Filesystem API to read and write any photos that a user selects.
>   [*Storage API*](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage)